# django -- can we combine two validators in one method

Tags: django

I want to use just one method to validate the file extention and the file size. is this possible by multiple if

````
```def validate_file_extension(value):

   ext = os.path.splitext(value.name)[1]
   valid_extensions = ['.tar.gz', '.tgz', '.tar', '.gz', 'tar.xz', '.zip']
   if not ext in valid_extensions:
   raise ValidationError(u'File not supported, Please upload only .tar.gz / 
   .tgz / .zip')```
````

and

```
filesize= value.size
    
    if filesize > 10485760:
        raise ValidationError("The maximum file size that can be uploaded is 10MB")
    else:
        return value
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the same method? It's much cleaner to separate the methods in 2 so it's easier to read.

Comment: because i don't have to change the model. I just have to add this to the existing validator thats already included in the model.

Comment: You can call other functions inside the validator

Comment: that is what i want to know how that could be done

Answer (score 0):

You could seperate each validator {seperation of concern principle} using different custom method.

```
def validate_file_mime():


def validate_file_size():

class ObjectModel():
     file = models.FileField(validators[validate_file_mime,validate_file_size])
```

Tested and it works!! kindly upvote...